# how to connect the external cam for android tablet using usb

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

> I need to connect External cam with android based tablet using usb and i need to save photos and videos.can any one help me on developing the app

Answer (score 0):

If your mobile have the standard **USB mass storage driver** then it will be detected automatically when you connect it to your device but if it has a **custom driver** or **company specific** then it will not work on you device.